# Integration of $f(x)+g(x)$ from $x=-3$ to $x =3$ where both $f$ and $g$ are odd functions

Tags: integration

Calculate

$$\int_{-3}^{3}[f(x)+g(x)]dx$$

where $f$ and $g$ are odd functions.

Comment: To get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Proper formatting is expected; for some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: The sum of two odd functions is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, if $f$ is odd then the value of the integral between n and -n is 0. That's because you have the same curve but upside down, so its area is the same and negative. Now applying the linearity of the integral we are done.